# Why is my timeOut function called twice?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, settimeout

I created the next plugin. it does a function with a timeout, very easy. When I use the plugin, the callback function is called twice though, can anyone explain why?

@EDIT: Ok, this only happens when I type really fast. It's like the cearTimeout is called to late, and the timeOuts stack up.

```
// Create closure.
(function ($) {

    // Plugin definition.
    $.fn.autoUpdate = function (options) {
        var parameters = $.extend({}, $.fn.autoUpdate.defaults, options);

        // traverse all nodes
        this.each(function () {
            var timeOut = null;
            $(this).bind("keyup", function () {
                timeOut = setTimeout(function () {
                    parameters.callBack.call(this);
                }, parameters.timeOut);
            });
            $(this).bind("keydown", function () {
                clearTimeout(timeOut);
            });

            // allow jQuery chaining
            return this;
        })
    };

    // Private function for debugging.
    function debug(obj) {
        if (window.console && window.console.log) {
            window.console.log(obj);
        }
    };

    $.fn.autoUpdate.defaults = {
        timeOut: 2000,
        callBack: function () {
            debug('callback called');
        }
    };

// End of closure.

})(jQuery);
```

in HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    $('#email-address').autoUpdate({
      timeOut: 2000,
      callBack: function () {
        console.log('email');
      }
    });

    $('#password').autoUpdate({
      timeOut: 2000,
      callBack: function () {
        console.log('password');
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Not sure, but how many `nodes` could it be traversing in the `each` function?

Comment: its only one, it seems the problem is when I type very fast, the keyup and keydown start stacking, so they are not called at the proper time. for example keyDown might be called 3 times before keyup is called.

Comment: Then you could also clear the timeout each time on keyup before setting it again meaning you would only have one at a time as opposed to 3.

Comment: @RobSchmuecker yes, that's what I did, and it did solve the problem, but does anyone have any insight in why this happens ?

Comment: If you have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/q6y5nxg7/ , often when typing fast, you press several buttons before you actually release the first ones.  That is I'm guessing why it happens.